# Symfony Commands from command line

Tags: php, symfony

Can anyone tell me from I have to execute Symfony commands on command line like,
`php app/console -V` ?

My project is in `C:xampp/htdocs/myproject`.
I'm running it from `cd xampp/htdocs/` but not success.

Comment: `app` is usually in your project directory so running the command from htdocs where that folder doesn't exist doesn't make too much sense. We need more information though. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: what about `cd xampp/htdocs/myproject` and then trying to run `php app/console -V` ?

Comment: As others have observed, you generally want to run app/console from within the myproject directory. Also, can you describe to us what "not success" looks like? And confirm that you're definitely using Symfony 2? :)

Comment: @Imi Borbas: its also not working the error is `php is not recognized as internal or external command`

Comment: @Matt : yes i m using symfony2 dowloaded symfony standard edition from `http://symfony.com/download`

Comment: Thanks all.I found the solution, i had to set the path to symfony project....

Comment: @SalmanAli: how did you solved this, Share with us

Comment: gowri, i was using wrong path to app/conosle ...

Answer (score 0):

You must running your command from `xampp/htdocs/myproject` and not from `xampp/htdocs`.

If problem persist see the documentation about the [Console Componant](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html).

Hope this help.